# Android login using mysql of live server error

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to Android and I have this code from Android Hive. It runs well but when I use my e-mail and password to login which uses the data of MySQL from live server the app stops to run and shows an error in logcat.

Here is the code:

```
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Create login session
                            session.setLogin(true);

                            // Launch main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

It shows error when it goes inside it.
Here is the logcat:

```
07-23 04:02:16.554: W/dalvikvm(1336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at com.example.ss_suppliers.LoginActivity.checkLogin(LoginActivity.java:165)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at com.example.ss_suppliers.LoginActivity.access$2(LoginActivity.java:99)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at com.example.ss_suppliers.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:72)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-23 04:02:16.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1336):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Where is your logcat??? Post it

Comment: i have posted it plese view it and help me